# How to Define Dependencies of Libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The project I am working on uses the appboy library. Unfortunately this lib depends on the v4 support library and uses [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setColorScheme(int...)) depreciated method. I want to update the support library to version 21.0.0 but I get the following error message.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme

How can I configure gradle so the appboy library uses an older support lib(preferable 20.0.0) but the project uses 21.0.0?

I import appboy like so

compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.5.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appboy has updated the Android SDK to use version 21 of the support library; this issue is resolved in the most current release.

Comment: yup, I asked them to :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to use support library v21.0.0 with older version of android.

Just include the new AppCompat v21.0.0 and **change the compilation version of your project into android 5.0**

Comment: I am compiling against 21. The problem is the library is using a method that has been removed from the support library